# How To Migrate CiviCRM From Wordpress To Drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

We are using CiviCRM with Wordpress and would like to switch it to Drupal. I have created a fresh Drupal/CiviCRM install and gave CiviCRM it's own database. How do I go about transferring the data from the old Wordpress site to the new Drupal site?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that a) you gave CiviCRM a separate database under Wordpress, and b) you installed the same version of CiviCRM under Drupal:

- Dump the current CiviCRM database to a .sql file.
- Load that database into Drupal.
- Review "[Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location)" for relevant details regarding deleting caches etc.
- Delete all the entries out of the `civicrm_uf_match` table in the CiviCRM database (while logged in as user 1).
- Go to **Administer menu > Users and Permissions > Synchronize Users to Contacts**.

That should repopulate your `civicrm_uf_match` table and thus connect your Drupal users to contacts.  Log out and log in again (in a different browser) to make sure everything looks good - and clear your caches again!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Yes Wordpress has it's own Civi database and it's the same version as Drupal. Unfortunately, when I try to import the Wordpress database into Drupal, I get this error: [ERROR in query 7] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation. 

What does that mean?

Comment: Also, when you say "Dump" do you mean export via phpMyAdmin (or Sequel Pro)?

Comment: Yeah, export via the tool of your choice - phpMyAdmin works!  As for the error - that really deserves its own question, so I posted the question (and answer) here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/619/why-do-i-get-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-f/620#620