# CiviCRM database issue with views and the definer

Tags: wordpress, database

We have a website using CiviCRM that was recently switched from Drupal to WordPress as well as to a new server.

Everything on the website is working properly and they have had no issues with CiviCRM.

The problem: The websites and databases are backed up every night and the old backups are deleted upon completion of the backups. The CiviCRM database backup is failing because the database has 2 views (civicrm_view_case_activity_recent and civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming) which have a "definer" which was carried over from the last server and does not exist on the new server.

The question(s): Is there a way to redefine the definer without recreating those views?

If not, is there code available to recreate those views?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration error: “The user specified as a definer does not exist”](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/migration-error-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist)

Comment: There's an answer listed here that should help you: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/20779/181

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to recreate the views using the following script. (It also recreates the triggers and stored functions that can have the same problem

```
<?php
   civicrm_initialize();
   Civi::service('sql_triggers')->rebuild(null, false);
   CRM_Case_BAO_Case::createCaseViews();
```

Run the script with `drush scr <script.php>`