# Migrate from Drupal To Joomla

Tags: drupal, joomla

I have completed the following steps:

- sql backup civicrm database from Drupal
- create fresh joomla install (3.6)
- install fresh civicrm (4.2 - same as on drupal install)
- import and replace civicrm tables from sql backup into the Joomla database

all seemed to be going well, but now when I log into the admin area I am getting a white screen stating

> > Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error:
> >     unknown error Return to home page.

it then logs me out,

when i check the error_log on the server it states:

> ```
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gd.so' -
> ```
>
> /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/gd.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
>   0

also, in PHPmyadmin when i try to edit a civicrm table i get the following error:

> **#1449 - The user specified as a definer ('civicrm'@'localhost') does not exist**

if anyone can advise on how to correct please advise :-)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a new server as well. The first sounds like a PHP issue - some kind of mismatch for the GD extension in php.ini or php-gd rpm package is not even installed. When I say extension I mean PHP extension, nothing to do with CiviCRM other than GD might be used by CiviCRM, but it's usually installed by default. In joomla admin you can go into site system information and see the output from phpinfo to see if it's installed.

The second is probably a mysql trigger/view issue, where you have a different mysql user for your joomla database than the one that created the original civicrm trigger/view. You can either create and use the same mysql user (civicrm@localhost) for your database, or recreate the trigger/views manually. A third option is start again and edit the sql file and edit the part of the trigger/view creation that sets the definer before you import it to the mysql user that you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that such an old version of CiviCRM would work on a modern version of Joomla.  You'll also want to upgrade for security reasons.  I would recommend upgrading CiviCRM on Drupal before migrating to Joomla, and your "Unknown Error" will likely disappear.

Also, to troubleshoot the "Unknown Error", turn on debug mode and backtraces:  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  If you're not sure what to do, please update the question with the expanded debugging info.

Demerit is correct about the definer error.  [See here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/619/why-do-i-get-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-f/620#620) to fix that error.