# How to export/import Civi CRM?

Tags: wordpress

How to export/import  Civi CRM  all database  (profile, custom field, contacts etc) with same setting in WordPress?

Comment: Hi Rajesh - could you explain what you are trying to do, that would help in trying to answer your question.  If you are moving from one server to another - there is a solution for that - if you are moving to another CRM - there is a solution for that too.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackExchange Rajesh!  The simplest option is to dump and load the database (eg using `mysqldump`).  If you need something different, edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching your cms from drupal/joomla to wordpress then there are instructions here. https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-cms/

If you are wanting to "clone" an existing set up using mysqldump there is a perl script that you will want to run to remove the "definer": statements.

```
perl -pi -e 's#\/\*\!5001[7|3].*?`[^\*]*\*\/##g' /path/to/mysqldump.sql
```

More info on this thread.

[Why do I get "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation" when importing a SQL dump to CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/619/why-do-i-get-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-f)