drupal to wordpress fatal error
Civicrm 5.65 on both Drupal and word press
Exported from drupal:structure and data minus 3 @ cache files, settings and domain.
Cleared uf_match except for one WP admin user linked to civi contact record
Cleared templates_c. Cleared browser cache. Disabled word fence.
Confirmed dbase user and dbase correct in settings.php and dbase
Retained civi extensions from initial WP install. Disabled all extensions from import. Error when activating civi is "Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [-18: DB Error: no such table thrown in /home/website/public_html/new/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 954.
Nothing in civi log as never opens obs, Not sure where else I can trouble shoot

Can you clarify the steps you took in creating your database dump before you moved it? You may want to search here for 'skip triggers' eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7504/how-to-migrate-database-without-logs/10709#10709 and/or 'perl' for eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30521/how-to-export-import-civi-crm/30638#30638

Thank you so much petednz. Exporting without triggers was the answer. Do I add this as an answer now?

You may want to search here for 'skip triggers' eg https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7504/how-to-migrate-database-without-logs/10709#10709
